# composer cannot find package friendsofsymfony/user-bundle

Tags: php, symfony, composer-php

I have a problem with composer.
when I use this command in cmd

```
php composer.phar require friendsofsymfony/user-bundle
```

I get this message

```
Please provide a version constraint for the friendsofsymfony/user-bundle requirement: 2.0.*@dev
composer.json has been updated
Loading composer repositories with package information
Updating dependencies (including require-dev)
Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.

Problem 1
    - The requested package friendsofsymfony/user-bundle could not be found in any version, there may be a typo in the package name.

Potential causes:
    - A typo in the package name
    - The package is not available in a stable-enough version according to your minimum-stability setting
   see <https://groups.google.com/d/topic/composer-dev/_g3ASeIFlrc/discussion> for more details.

   Read <http://getcomposer.org/doc/articles/troubleshooting.md> for further common problems.

Installation failed, reverting composer.json to its original content.
```

and composer.json file:

```
{
"name": "symfony/framework-standard-edition",
"description": "The \"Symfony Standard Edition\" distribution",
"autoload": {
    "psr-0": { "": "src/" }
},
"require": {
    "php": ">=5.3.3",
    "symfony/symfony": "2.2.*",
    "doctrine/orm": "~2.2,>=2.2.3",
    "doctrine/doctrine-bundle": "1.2.*",
    "twig/extensions": "1.0.*",
    "symfony/assetic-bundle": "2.1.*",
    "symfony/swiftmailer-bundle": "2.2.*",
    "symfony/monolog-bundle": "2.2.*",
    "sensio/distribution-bundle": "2.2.*",
    "sensio/framework-extra-bundle": "2.2.*",
    "sensio/generator-bundle": "2.2.*",
    "jms/security-extra-bundle": "1.4.*",
    "jms/di-extra-bundle": "1.3.*",
    "gregwar/captcha-bundle": "dev-master",
    "eko/feedbundle": "dev-master"
},
"scripts": {
    "post-install-cmd": [
        "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::buildBootstrap",
        "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::clearCache",
        "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::installAssets",
        "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::installRequirementsFile"
    ],
    "post-update-cmd": [
        "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::buildBootstrap",
        "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::clearCache",
        "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::installAssets",
        "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::installRequirementsFile"
    ]
},
"config": {
    "bin-dir": "bin"
},
"minimum-stability": "dev",
"extra": {
    "symfony-app-dir": "app",
    "symfony-web-dir": "web",
    "branch-alias": {
        "dev-master": "2.2-dev"
    }
}
}
```

Composer version is 6a1262e675b5c1c2c7b1cc58a14028f67885b880

Can somebody tell me what I do wrong please?

Answer (score 3):

You surely have 
`{"minimum-stability": "stable"}` , in your composer.json, set it to

```
{"minimum-stability": "dev"}
```

It's because you choose a development version of `FOSUserBundle (2.0.*@dev)` and composer can't find this version due to the minimum-stability.

Comment: I already did that. minimun-stabiity is dev. will put my composer.json in above post too.

Comment: Put "friendsofsymfony/user-bundle": "2.0.*@dev" directly in composer.json, then run composer.phar update

Comment: Getting same error - The requested package friendsofsymfony/user-bundle could not be found in any version, there may be a typo in the package name.

Comment: Ok, change 2.0.*@dev to dev-master

Comment: result of composer self-update: You are using the latest composer version.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/33557/discussion-between-amir-sh-and-rpg600)

Answer (score 1):

Had the same problem just now and solved it with a slight change to what Rpg600 suggested:

Put "friendsofsymfony/user-bundle": "2.0.*@dev" directly in composer.json, then run

```
$ composer.phar update friendsofsymfony/user-bundle
```

The only thing I did different to what Rpg600 suggested was to specify the bundle to update but in my case this worked.